# realloc не срабатывает

Tags: c, функции, realloc

realloc не срабатывает

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h> //FOR WINDOWS ONLY

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
typedef char _TCHAR;
#define _tmain main
#endif



// Структура двогичного (бинарного) дерева

struct btree {
    double data; // данные
    struct btree *left; // левая ветвь
    struct btree *right; // правая ветвь
    struct btree *parent; // родитель
};

bool read_arg(char**, signed long long int**); // сигн. ф. считывания команд

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

// Динамические массивы
char *command_comblock; // Массив комманд
signed long long int *value_comblock; // Массив значений

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ КОММАНДЫ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

//Включаем русский в консоли
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); //FOR WINDOWS ONLY

// Ввод и анализ на верность комманд
if (read_arg(&command_comblock, &value_comblock) != true) {
    // Если что-то пошло не так при вводе в первый раз (попробуем еще разок)
    if (read_arg(&command_comblock, &value_comblock) != true) {
        // Что-то явно не так со вводом (тест на похмелье :D)

        // ScreenCleaner
        system("cls"); // FOR WINDOWS ONLY
        // system("clear"); //FOR LINUX ONLY

        // Выдача ошибки
        return 315;
    }
}

// Разбор введеных аргументов
system("pause");
return 0;
}

bool read_arg(char** command_comblock, signed long long int** value_comblock) {
// ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ
char temp;

// Первоначальное выделение места массивам
if ((*command_comblock = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
    printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
    return false;
}

if ((*value_comblock = (signed long long int *)malloc
    (sizeof(signed long long int))) == NULL) {
    printf("Realloc Error! [value_comblock]");
    return false;
}

// Непосредственное считывание
printf("Вводите комманды, как в k806.ru [Для Win. Ctrl+Z -> конец ввода]\n");
*value_comblock[0] = 0;
*command_comblock[0] = 0;
while (temp != EOF) {
    temp = getchar();
    switch (temp) {

        // Операция вывода дерева
    case 'p':
        *value_comblock[0]=*value_comblock[0]+1;
        if ((*command_comblock = (char*)realloc(*command_comblock,
            ((*value_comblock[0])*sizeof(char)))) == NULL) {
            printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
            return false;
        }
        printf("%d", sizeof(*command_comblock));
        *command_comblock[*value_comblock[0]-1] = temp;
        break;

    //
    }

}

return true;
}
```

Я думаю - проблема здесь

```
if ((*command_comblock = (char*)realloc(*command_comblock,
        ((*value_comblock[0])*sizeof(char)))) == NULL) {
        printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
        return false;
```

Или здесь

```
*command_comblock[*value_comblock[0]-1] = temp;
```

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимании "не срабатывает"? Как именно не срабатывает? Что происходит? Что, по-вашему, должно происходить? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: При вводе ppppp, например
Должен забиваться массив command_comblock
НО! В него забивается только на 1е место (выделенное еще маллоком) p а далее размер массива не увеличивается при реаллоке и программа вылетает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в приоритетах операций `*` и `[ ]`.

У операции индекса `[ ]` приоритет выше, чем у операции разыменовывания адреса `*`, т.е. всюду, где вы пишите `*x[i]` надо писать `(*x)[i]`:

```
(*value_comblock)[0] = 0;
(*command_comblock)[0] = 0;
...
  (*value_comblock)[0]++;
  if ((*command_comblock = realloc(*command_comblock, (*value_comblock)[0] * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
    printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
    return false;
  }
...
(*command_comblock)[(*value_comblock)[0]-1] = temp;
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Вы прям спасли меня, уже 3й день ночами не спал из-за этого нюанса языка